# Interaction between raw position signals and portfolio optimisation methodologies

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory

I'm trying to get my head around how the various aspects of constructing a final position generally interact and wonder whether anyone could expand on my (tentative) understanding currently.

As I see it currently, one may have a series of 'signals' which give an output of a 'position' (for the sake of simplicity, let's say this position is just {-1 .. 1}) on a set of instruments. However from here, I'm not entirely clear on any 'standard' method of aggregating these. Some thoughts being:

- It seems like (from things like Advances in Financial Machine Learning) that one can simply average (potentially with weighting) these into an aggregate final position.
- However I'm not sure where something like HRP/CLA comes into it, would one use this across different instruments after using averaging across signals within an instrument?
- Or would one use your portfolio optimisation across your set of signals treating each one as an individual 'instrument'?
- How does this work if your signal has a position in multiple instruments? Obviously you don't want the different legs to be weighted differently as then you're doing something different to your goal. Does one treat this spread as a distinct 'instrument' from each underlying leg?